# Reading multiple pins via registers on the Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due

I would like to read multiple pins at once in Arduino Due via registers just like PINB, PINC, PIND of the arduino uno. I know that the pins will be scattered to multiple registers, but i deduce it would still be faster this way since there for sure there will be multiple pins on a single register rather than call digitalRead 40 times.

Arduino shared the documentation for what digital/analog pins corressponds to the what ports to the actual sam chip, i just need that snippet of code that reads via registers.

So if any can give me the equivalents to these, It would be greatly appreciated:

- DDRx - The Port C Data Direction Register - read/write
- PORTx - The Port C Data Register - read/write
- PINx - The Port C Input Pins Register - read only

Comment: i just wrote x because there are three of those e.g. DDRB,DDRC,DDRD. basing from that there should be port A but i guess they dont use those

Answer (score 1):

You will find a good introduction on using port registers [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation). It also mentions some cons and pros of using port manipulation.

Comment: that documentation only applies to arduino boards using ATmega8 and ATmega168 chips, It does not apply to the due which uses a  SAM3x ARM chip

Comment: You are right. I didn't read your headline carefully enough. But apparently this question has been asked (and answered before): https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9117/sam3x8e-arduino-due-pin-io-registers

Comment: Wow I did not see that, it will be useful to me in future projects. Unfortunatly they are only talking about writing to the pins and not reading the pins. I could not find a mention on reading pins. Although I may have found a hint from a answer of this [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/35457/the-fastest-way-to-read-out-a-digital-pin-state-in-an-arduino-due?noredirect=1&lq=1), I will have to start from there i guess